# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am getting below error whenever I am running my project. This is happening from the time I installed DotNetOpenAuth.

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The located   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet
>    (Partial)
>   WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
>   WRN: Assembly Name: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet | Domain ID: 2
>   WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly

I also get below warning while building the project.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

There is absolutely no information as to what is going wrong here. Can someone help me debug as to what is the issue. I am trying to fix this from past 2 days but had no luck whatsoever.

Edit: Here is the packages.config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CodeContracts.Unofficial" version="1.0.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45"     />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your packages.config file, you have multiple versions of each package installed.  Your site won't function properly until you've cleaned this up--especially with respect to WebAPI and MVC.  Your best bet is to do a Clean, remove all of these non-client-side packages (you can leave jQuery and other client-side libraries), and re-add whichever version you need.  You only want 1 version of each when all is said and done.

If you really, really wanted to make this work without cleaning up your packages.config, you could setup assemblyRedirection in web.config (See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) and point all requests for 1 version to the other.

You'll need to check the WebPages, MVC and WebAPI version references mentioned in all web.config files in your web app to be sure they are referring to the correct versions as well.

Comment: I commented out lower revisions of duplicate dlls, cleaned up packages folder, re-installed them and added the references. I have the issue resolved but there is another problem now. It seems that the CSS/Bootstrap/JQuery has stopped working on my site. Not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry.  I edited my comment to suggest leaving client-side libraries as-is.  I guess I was too late.  Compare the versions that you have installed now to the ones you pasted above.  You probably just need to edit your index.cshtml file or BundleConfig.cs in the App_Start folder if you're using bundling to point to the new versions.  If you have compatibility issues, you can uninstall the versions just installed and install specific the exact versions you had before using Package Manager Console's Install-Package command for each package (e.g., Install-Package jQuery -Version 2.1.1).

Comment: BundleConfig.cs got screwed up with the changes that I did recently. I have now added back the references for jquery, css, bootstrap libraries and it all works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you installed it whit [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/) it should install all references needed.

For further assistence please provide packages.config

Comment: It got installed along with Microsoft WebPages OAuth library. I have added the packages.congfig above. You can see multiple versions for some dlls as I updated visual studio 2013 to update 3.

Comment: Remove all duplicates packages and references, and then start installing them one by one with Nuget.

That would be how i would try to solve it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, did the same. Removed older revisions, cleaned up packages folder and let nuget download the missing packages. Have the project working now. Thanks.

Comment: Good job! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had to go Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and update the DotNet*.* packages. Note that the solution I am working on is a group project hosted on an SVN. If one person updates their packages it may affect other users until they also update.